# Wierd LSM303DLHC magnetometer output

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, c++, magnetometer

I'm kind of new to electronic and recently bought a [Adafruit 9DOF Sensor](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-9-dof-imu-breakout). I use it with a Raspberry Pi Zero connected through I²C and when I try to read the Z-axis magnetic field data of the LSM303DLHC on it I always get 1111 0000  0000 0000, but the other axes output correct values.

To test it, I used a simple C code found on github, and after I got my incoherent result I searched on internet other ways to get them and tried for example using the address pointer of the chip but I got no better outputs.

The code I found ([link](https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/LSM303DLHC/blob/master/C/LSM303DLHC.c)):

```
    // Read zMag msb data from register(0x05)
    reg[0] = 0x05;
    write(file, reg, 1);
    read(file, data, 1);
    char data1_2 = data[0];

    // Read zMag lsb data from register(0x06)
    reg[0] = 0x06;
    write(file, reg, 1);
    read(file, data, 1);
    char data1_3 = data[0];
```

Is my sensor broken? Is there another way to get the data?

Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: You don't have to set the register to 6; it increments automatically each time you read from it. I don't think that's the cause of your problem, though.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I also thought that was the problem and tried to read the datas with a simple `read(file,buf,6)`, but got the same result...